# Jquery working only for one item in the list

Tags: jquery, django

In this piece of code data is being fetch from the backend that is in Django. I have list of products in Django some having variations and others don't have them by variation I mean like pizza that come in small, medium and large size each having there own price.

**Problem:** I want that all the items with variation should have changing price but this is not happening on the front end at the backend the prices are changing. Only the first product in the list is changing the prices but not all. (backend is working completely fine I checked the source code )

**productlist.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<script>

{% block jquery %}

function setPrice(){
    var price = $(".variation_select option:selected").attr("data-price")

    var sale_price = $(".variation_select option:selected").attr("data-sale-price")
    if (sale_price != "" && sale_price != "None" && sale_price != null ) {
    $("#price").html("<h4>" + sale_price + " <small class='og-price'>" + price + "</small></h4>");
    } else {
    $("#price").html(price);
    }

}
setPrice()

$(".variation_select").change(function(){
    setPrice()

})


{% endblock %}  

</script>


{% block content %}




<div class="row">
{% for object in object_list %}
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    {% if object.productimage_set.count > 0 %}

    {% for img in object.productimage_set.all %}
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class='img-responsive' src="{{ img.image.url }}" >


    {% endfor %} 

    {% endif %}



      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{ object.title }}</h3>

        <form id='add-form' method='GET' action="{% url 'cart' %}">
        <p id='jquery-message' class='lead'></p>

        {% if object.variation_set.count > 1 %}
        <h4 id='price'>{{ object.variation_set.first.price }}</h4>

        <select name= 'item' class='form-control variation_select'>
                {% for vari_obj in object.variation_set.all %}
                    <option data-sale-price="{{vari_obj.sale_price}}" data-price="{{ vari_obj.price }}" value="{{ vari_obj.id }}">{{ vari_obj }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>


        {% else %}
                <input type="hidden" name='item' value='{{ object.variation_set.first.id }}' />
                    <h4 id="price">{% if object.variation_set.first.sale_price %}

                    {{ object.variation_set.first.sale_price }}
                    <small class="og-price">{{ object.variation_set.first.price }}</small>

                    {% else %}

                    {{ object.variation_set.first.price }}

                    {% endif %}

                </h4>




        {% endif %}

        <p>{{object.description}}</p>
        <input class='form-control' type='number' name='qty' value='1' /> 
        <br></br>
        <p><input id='submit-btn' type='submit'  value='Add to Cart' class="btn btn-primary" />


        </p>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you please add your html?

Comment: This is the html

Comment: Are the additional items in the list being loaded via AJAX?

Comment: no I am not loading any items from AJAX

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help to put your jQuery at the bottom of the page, not the top. You are trying to attach an event to the select trigger of your DOM element (.variation_select) which at that specific time does not yet exsist.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in function setPrices, is that it's taking the first element with class .variation_select

you should try some as follow, to take the change from all elements with class .variation_select:

```
$(".variation_select").change(function(){
    var price = $(this).attr("data-price");

    var sale_price = $(this).attr("data-sale-price");

    if (sale_price != "" && sale_price != "None" && sale_price != null ) {
        $("#price").html("<h4>" + sale_price + " <small class='og-price'>" + price + "</small></h4>");
    } else {
        $("#price").html(price);
    }
});
```